# How to capture an RTSP livestream via Java?

Tags: java, opencv

I know, there are several posts handling with this problem here on Stackoverflow, but I didn´t get a solution for my problem. I have an ipcam and I want to capture the livestream using java. The problem is, that I can only access the cam via RTSP. There is no normal http://xxx.xxx.xxx:xx access.
I use the OpenCv library but unfortunately my program only works with the webcam of my laptop because it is the default device.

```
protected void init()
    {
        this.capture = new VideoCapture();
        this.faceCascade = new CascadeClassifier();
        this.absoluteFaceSize = 0;
    }

    /**
     * The action triggered by pushing the button on the GUI
     */
    @FXML
    protected void startCamera()
    {
        // set a fixed width for the frame
        originalFrame.setFitWidth(600);
        // preserve image ratio
        originalFrame.setPreserveRatio(true);

        if (!this.cameraActive)
        {
            // disable setting checkboxes
            this.haarClassifier.setDisable(true);
            this.lbpClassifier.setDisable(true);

            // start the video capture
            //String URLName = "rtsp://username:password@rtsp:554/h264/ch1/main/av_stream";
            this.capture.open("rtsp://192.168.178.161:554/onvif1");


            // is the video stream available?
            if (this.capture.isOpened())
            {
                this.cameraActive = true;

                // grab a frame every 33 ms (30 frames/sec)
                Runnable frameGrabber = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Image imageToShow = grabFrame();
                        originalFrame.setImage(imageToShow);
                    }
                };

                this.timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                // update the button content
                this.cameraButton.setText("Stop Camera");
            }
            else
            {
                // log the error
                System.err.println("Failed to open the camera connection...");
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem? didnt the other solutions point you to the answer?? do you have the address of the camera? what is this.capture.open(rtsp://192.168.178.25)> is that a string in there or what?? and is the correct one for your camera?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot capture the stream. I have the ip address of the camera and now I want the program to show a stream of my cam but it is not showing anything.

Comment: I added the whole code, just that you see, that capture is a created object.